# Oracle trigger compilation error

Tags: sql, oracle11g

For the following trigger I am getting the following compilation errors: missing SET keyword, SQL Statement ignored (on line 2), Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:  ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with     << continue close current delete fetch lock  insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge (line 9(. I've searched through over 2 dozen examples and still can't figure out what kind of syntatical errors I'm making that are causing these compilation errors..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHANGE_RENTAL_RATE
BEFORE INSERT ON film FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE film
SELECT *
SET rental_rate = CASE special_features
              WHEN 'Trailers' THEN rental_rate := :new.rental_rate + 0.1
              WHEN 'Commentaries' THEN rental_rate := new.rental_rate + 0.5
              WHEN 'Deleted Scenes' THEN rental_rate := new.rental_rate + 0.2
              WHEN 'Behind the Scenes' THEN rental_rate := new.rental_rate - 0.2
END;
/
```

Comment: Remove the `select *`; it is not part of an `update` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update statement doesn't make sense because it is affecting all the rows in `film`.  You are doing a "before" trigger.  Perhaps you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHANGE_RENTAL_RATE
BEFORE INSERT ON film FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if :new.special_features = 'Trailers' THEN :new.rental_rate := :new.rental_rate + 0.1;
    elsif :new.special_features = 'Commentaries' THEN :new.rental_rate := :new.rental_rate + 0.5;
    elsif :new.special_features = 'Deleted Scenes' THEN :new.rental_rate := :new.rental_rate + 0.2;
    elsif :new.special_features = 'Behind the Scenes' THEN :new.rental_rate := :new.rental_rate - 0.2;
    else :new.special_features := NULL
    end if;
END;
```